# Compare integers that trailing with zero

Tags: php

I needed to write a function that basically compare two integers but what the spacial case in that is i need to compare numbers trailed with zero, below is the example

```
$firstNumber = 1;
$secondNumber = 01;

if($firstNumber == $secondNumber){
   echo "Numbers are equal"
}else{
   echo "Numbers are not equal"
}
```

Basically the above code will return "Numbers are equal" But in my case, the numbers are not equal because the $secondNumber is prefixed with zero. So it should go to the else condition. How do i approach in this scenerio?

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: I haven't used PHP in a while, but I'm fairly certain `$secondNumber = 01` will make `$secondNumber` equal to `1`. The only way the 0 would remain is if the value was stored as a string.

Comment: I suppose this is PHP based on the use of `echo`. Why tag it with JS then?

Comment: Be careful with integer literals with preceeding zeros, as this is interpreted as an octal value. http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.integer.php

Comment: @Terry but the logic would be same for php and javascript, i guess

Comment: Note that your `echo` statements are missing the trailing `;` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Treat them as strings, and use the `===` [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

```
$firstNumber  = '1';
$secondNumber = '01';

if ($firstNumber === $secondNumber) {
   echo "Numbers are equal";
} else {
    echo "Numbers are not equal";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstNumber = 1;
$secondNumber = 01;

if ((int) $firstNumber == (int) $secondNumber){
   echo "Numbers are equal";
} else {
   echo "Numbers are not equal";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use integer values, 01 will be converted immediately to 1, right after you declared it. You should declare these values as a string to compare like this.